# Deleting files from connected devices doesn't free the device's storage

Tags: files, ram, delete, tablet

A few weeks ago, I bought my tablet and copied files from my computer running Ubuntu 12.04. Somehow, I had to delete some of these copied files to free some memory. But upon deletion from my computer, the memory of the (supposed to be) deleted files is still consumed. While the folders and files are already gone, they seem to be still consuming the device capacity. It happens with my memory card too, with a folder ".Trash-9999" when i reinsert it to my phone.

How do I completely rid off the the deleted files from my tablet? How do I do this without formatting the device partition?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is the problem I too have faced. the solution is very simple.

Let me explain. when you did delete your files from your device, they will move into Trash of your computer then you need to clear them from trash also.I mean you supposed to delete them permanently. Then only you can get the free space.

Comment: This would need to be done from Ubuntu, with the device attached. *Or, you could just remove the offending directory.*